# Python 3.7 dictionary giving wrong value as output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a text-based game in Python (I know, a very common beginner project) and I've come across a problem within nested dictionaries. Here is the dictionary code:

```
gamemap = {
    "a1": {
        ZONENAME : "Town Market",
        DESCRIPTION : "This is the area where most goods are bought and sold",
        EXAMINATION : "There are 3 people in this area. You can talk to them.",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "",
        DOWN : "b1",
        LEFT : "",
        RIGHT : "a2",
        KEY : "pizzeria"

        },
    "a2": {
        ZONENAME : "Town Entrance",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "",
        DOWN : "b2",
        LEFT : "a1",
        RIGHT : "a3"
        },
    "a3": {
        ZONENAME : "Town Square",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "",
        DOWN : "b3",
        LEFT : "a2",
        RIGHT : "a4"
        },
    "a4": {
        ZONENAME : "Town Hall",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "",
        DOWN : "b4",
        LEFT : "a3",
        RIGHT : ""
        },
    "b1": {
        ZONENAME : "School",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "a1",
        DOWN : "c1",
        LEFT : "",
        RIGHT : "b2"
        },
    "b2": {
        ZONENAME : "Home",
        DESCRIPTION : "This is where you live. It is your home.",
        EXAMINATION : "Your house is a bright pink colour. I'm not judging you, but... ok I'm judging you. I'm sorry.",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "a2",
        DOWN : "c2",
        LEFT : "b1",
        RIGHT : "b3"
        },
    "b3": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "",
        EXAMINATION : "",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "a3",
        DOWN : "c3",
        LEFT : "b2",
        RIGHT : "b4"
        },
    "b4": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "a4",
        DOWN : "c4",
        LEFT : "b3",
        RIGHT : ""
        },
    "c1": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "b1",
        DOWN : "d1",
        LEFT : "",
        RIGHT : "c2"
        },
    "c2": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "b2",
        DOWN : "d2",
        LEFT : "c1",
        RIGHT : "c3"
        },
    "c3": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "b3",
        DOWN : "d3",
        LEFT : "c2",
        RIGHT : "c4"
        },
    "c4": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "b4",
        DOWN : "d4",
        LEFT : "c3",
        RIGHT : ""
        },
    "d1": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "c1",
        DOWN : "",
        LEFT : "",
        RIGHT : "d2"
        },
    "d2": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "c2",
        DOWN : "",
        LEFT : "d1",
        RIGHT : "d3"
        },
    "d3": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "c3",
        DOWN : "",
        LEFT : "d2",
        RIGHT : "d4"
        },
    "d4": {
        ZONENAME : "",
        DESCRIPTION : "description",
        EXAMINATION : "examine",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "c4",
        DOWN : "",
        LEFT : "d3",
        RIGHT : ""
        }

}
```

It looks fine, right? Have a look at this:

```
def print_location():
    current_place = "You are in the " + gamemap[myPlayer.location][ZONENAME]
    for character in current_place:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.03)
```

As you can see, this function is telling the player where they are, printing the ZONENAME variable. This works for most of them. For example, if I go to a2, it prints "You are in the Town Entrance".

However, if I go to a1, even though the code in that function is the same, instead of printing: "You are in the Town Market", which is what ZONENAME is for that area, it prints "You are in the pizzeria". "pizzeria" is the value of KEY for a1, not zonename.

What's odd is that if I comment out or remove the key, it prints the correct thing: "You are in the Town Market".

I have tried adding the KEY value on the other nested dicts, and the problem is persistent. As soon as I add that variable, it prints that instead. It is very confusing. I have also tried changing the name of KEY but that didn't work either.

Please help fix this. If you need any more of the script to look at, I can provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `print(ZONENAME)` and `print(KEY)` output the same thing?

Comment: @ArdaOzden, can you provide what are your values of `ZONENAME`, ..., `RIGHT`? I mean all of the keys you are passing variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is with your Dictionary definitions. I pared down your example for space.

```
ZONENAME="ZONENAME"
KEY="ZONENAME"
# ...
gamemap = {
  "a1": {
    ZONENAME : "Town Market",
    KEY : "pizzeria"
    },
  "a2": {
    ZONENAME : "Town Entrance",
    },
}
```

for ZONENAME, LEFT, etc you're using variable names instead of string literals. Now these are probably defined somewhere in your program so the program still runs fine, but its misleading. I'd be willing to bet that the variable KEY is defined as "ZONENAME" somewhere before your dictionary definitions.

What this actually looks like in the program is:

```
gamemap = {
  "a1": {
    "ZONENAME" : "Town Market",
    "ZONENAME" : "pizzeria" #  Overwrites Town Market key
    },
  "a2": {
    "ZONENAME" : "Town Entrance",
    },
}
```

Wrap your Variable names in single or double quotes and I believe you'll get the behavior you expect from this function, but this might break something else in your program.

```
gamemap = {
  "a1": {
    "ZONENAME" : "Town Market",
    "KEY" : "pizzeria"
    },
  "a2": {
    "ZONENAME" : "Town Entrance",
    },
  # ...
}
def print_location():
    current_place = "You are in the " + gamemap[playerLocation][ZONENAME]
    print(current_place)
```

Now when we run

```
playerLocation = "a1"
ZONENAME = "ZONENAME"
print_location()
# prints: You are in the Town Market

ZONENAME = "KEY"
print_location()
# prints: You are in the Pizzaria
```

See this link to run the code yourself: https://repl.it/repls/MajesticMeanAutosketch

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an extra line in a1 after KEYS, does removing it do anything?

Also, you might want to put strings around ZONENAME, KEY, DESCRIPTION etc.

I would have commented this but I don't have enough rep :(